# How close does the graph $y=\sqrt{x}$ come to the point $(1/2,16)$

Tags: calculus

I am having a slight problem with the following question. Here's my attempt;

let $(\sqrt{u},u)$ be any point on the curve, we are to find the minimum value of the function;
$$f(u)= (\sqrt{u}-\dfrac{1}{2})^2 +(u-16)^2$$
$$f(u)=u^2-31u-\sqrt{u}+\dfrac{1025}{4}$$

To find critical points of $f(u)$, we have to find the solution of $f'(u)=0$;

$$f'(u)=2u-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}-31=0$$

Setting $\sqrt{u}=x$,the equation becomes;
 $$2x^2-\dfrac{1}{2x}-31=0$$

$$4x^3-62x-1=0$$

Now, I am stuck here as my book says the answer should be $7/2 \sqrt{17}$ and don't think the answer can be this nice.

Is my understanding of the problem correct?

Is an alternative approach possible?

Comment: Any point on the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$ should take the form $(u, \sqrt{u})$, and hence, $f(u) = (u - \frac{1}{2})^2 + (\sqrt{u}-16)^2$.

Comment: @Petaro Thanks, Is there any alternative approach for this type of problems?

Comment: Michael Hoppe's solution below is another approach.

Answer (score 2):

As Petaro commented, you need to minimize $$f(x) = (x - \frac{1}{2})^2 + (\sqrt{x}-16)^2$$ from which, after minor simplifications, $$f'(x)=2 x-\frac{16}{\sqrt{x}}$$ which cancels for $x=4$.

So I don't see how the book could report this answer.

Comment: I am done with the problem, is there an alternative approach?

Comment: This is the simplest formulation of the problem. Frankly speaking, I don't see any other.

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the line joining $(1/2,16)$ and $(a,\sqrt{a})$ is $\frac{16-\sqrt{a}}{1/2-a}$. Now the tangent in $a$ has slope $1/2\sqrt{a}$. The tangent and the line must be perpendicular, so the product of the slopes must be $-1$. This yields $2a\sqrt{a}=16$, thus $a=4$.

Comment: why should the tangent and line be perpendicular?

Comment: Because we're looking for the shortest line connecting the point and the function.  Feel free to draw a picture, please.

Answer (score 1):

As Petaro observed in his comment, the general point of the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ is of the form $(u, \sqrt{u})$ and not $(\sqrt{u}, u)$.

I suggest you to work with $(t^2, t)$, for $t\geq 0$, to get rid of the sqare root.